# Platform class java.util.Currency requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

Getting error while using `Moshi code gen` for data class with `Currency`.

Referred similar questions. (Adding referred question at the end)

Error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform class java.util.Currency requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

**Moshi Builder**

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(CurrencyJsonAdapter())
    // .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()
private val initialDatabaseDataJsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<InitialDatabaseData> =
    moshi.adapter(InitialDatabaseData::class.java)
```

`InitialDatabaseData` is a data class that has `val sources: List<Source>,` as one of its fields.
`Source` data class in turn has,

```
@field:Json(name = "balance_amount")
val balanceAmount: Amount = Amount(
    value = 0,
),
```

**Amount data class**

```
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass
import java.util.Currency

const val CURRENCY_CODE_INR = "INR"

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Amount(
    val currency: Currency = Currency.getInstance(CURRENCY_CODE_INR),
    val value: Long = 0,
) {
    fun toSignedString(): String {
        val formattedValue = formattedCurrencyValue(
            value = value,
        )
        return if (value > 0) {
            "${currency.symbol} +$formattedValue"
        } else {
            "${currency.symbol} $formattedValue"
        }
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        val formattedValue = formattedCurrencyValue(
            value = value,
        )
        return "${currency.symbol} $formattedValue"
    }

    operator fun plus(
        amount: Amount,
    ): Amount {
        return Amount(
            currency = currency,
            value = value + amount.value,
        )
    }
}
```

**Custom Adapter for Currency**

```
import com.squareup.moshi.FromJson
import com.squareup.moshi.ToJson
import java.util.Currency

class CurrencyJsonAdapter {
    @ToJson
    fun toJson(
        currency: Currency,
    ): String {
        return currency.currencyCode
    }

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(
        currencyCodeString: String,
    ): Currency {
        return Currency.getInstance(currencyCodeString)
    }
}
```

**Dependencies**

```
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.13.0"
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.3"
kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.13.0"
```

**Note:**

1. Not looking for solutions using kotlin reflection. (Adding `.add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())` to `Moshi builder`)
2. Please add a comment if anything else is required.

Complete Error (if required)

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.makeappssimple.abhimanyu.financemanager.android.utils.JsonUtilKt.readInitialDataFromAssets(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.makeappssimple.abhimanyu.financemanager.android.data.local.database.MyRoomDatabase$Companion$populateInitialData$1$1.invokeSuspend(MyRoomDatabase.kt:176)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:39)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform class java.util.Currency requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered
    for class java.util.Currency currency
    for class com.makeappssimple.abhimanyu.financemanager.android.entities.amount.Amount balanceAmount
    for class com.makeappssimple.abhimanyu.financemanager.android.entities.source.Source
    for java.util.List<com.makeappssimple.abhimanyu.financemanager.android.entities.source.Source> sources
    for class com.makeappssimple.abhimanyu.financemanager.android.entities.initialdatabasedata.InitialDatabaseData
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi$LookupChain.exceptionWithLookupStack(Moshi.java:389)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:158)
        at com.makeappssimple.abhimanyu.financemanager.android.entities.amount.AmountJsonAdapter.<init>(AmountJsonAdapter.kt:30)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.generatedAdapter(Util.java:588)
        at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters$1.create(StandardJsonAdapters.java:61)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:146)
        at com.makeappssimple.abhimanyu.financemanager.android.entities.source.SourceJsonAdapter.<init>(SourceJsonAdapter.kt:30)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.generatedAdapter(Util.java:588)
        at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters$1.create(StandardJsonAdapters.java:61)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:146)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:106)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:75)
        at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter.newArrayListAdapter(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:54)
        at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter$1.create(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:38)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:146)
        at com.makeappssimple.abhimanyu.financemanager.android.entities.initialdatabasedata.InitialDatabaseDataJsonAdapter.<init>(InitialDatabaseDataJsonAdapter.kt:31)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.generatedAdapter(Util.java:588)
        at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters$1.create(StandardJsonAdapters.java:61)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:146)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:106)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:80)
        at com.makeappssimple.abhimanyu.financemanager.android.utils.JsonUtilKt.<clinit>(JsonUtil.kt:24)
            ... 10 more
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform class java.util.Currency requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered
        at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:76)
2022-04-05 03:57:46.008 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:146)
            ... 36 more
```

**Referred questions**

1. [Moshi: Platform class java.lang.Class requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66095850/moshi-platform-class-java-lang-class-requires-explicit-jsonadapter-to-be-regist)
2. [Retrofit/Moshi: Platform class java.util.Date requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64983666/retrofit-moshi-platform-class-java-util-date-requires-explicit-jsonadapter-to-b)
3. [Kotlin: Platform class java.sql.Timestamp requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69466462/kotlin-platform-class-java-sql-timestamp-requires-explicit-jsonadapter-to-be-re)
4. [Platform class android (with no annotations) requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59552354/platform-class-android-with-no-annotations-requires-explicit-jsonadapter-to-be)
5. [Platform java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> (with no annotations) requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67195054/platform-java-util-arraylistjava-lang-string-with-no-annotations-requires-ex)
6. [Moshi adapter creation failure: "requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62320292/moshi-adapter-creation-failure-requires-explicit-jsonadapter-to-be-registered)
7. [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform class java.time.LocalDateTime (with no annotations) requires explicit JsonAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972766/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-platform-class-java-time-localdatetime-with)

### Edit 1

**JsonUtil.kt**

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(CurrencyJsonAdapter())
    .build()
private val initialDatabaseDataJsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<InitialDatabaseData> =
    moshi.adapter(InitialDatabaseData::class.java)
private val databaseBackupDataJsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<DatabaseBackupData> =
    moshi.adapter(DatabaseBackupData::class.java)

class JsonUtil @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
) {
    fun readDatabaseBackupDataFromFile(
        uri: Uri,
    ): DatabaseBackupData? {
        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver

        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { inputStream ->
            BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use { bufferedReader ->
                var line: String? = bufferedReader.readLine()
                while (line != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line)
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine()
                }
            }
        }
        return databaseBackupDataJsonAdapter.fromJson(stringBuilder.toString())
    }

    fun writeDatabaseBackupDataToFile(
        uri: Uri,
        databaseBackupData: DatabaseBackupData,
    ) {
        val jsonString = databaseBackupDataJsonAdapter.toJson(databaseBackupData)
        writeJsonToFile(
            uri = uri,
            jsonString = jsonString,
        )
    }

    private fun writeJsonToFile(
        uri: Uri,
        jsonString: String,
    ) {
        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
        try {
            contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w")?.use {
                FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor).use { fileOutputStream ->
                    fileOutputStream.write(jsonString.toByteArray())
                }
            }
        } catch (fileNotFoundException: FileNotFoundException) {
            fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace()
        } catch (ioException: IOException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

fun readInitialDataFromAssets(
    context: Context,
): InitialDatabaseData? {
    val jsonString = readJsonFileFromAssets(
        context = context,
        fileName = "database/initial_data.json",
    ) ?: return null
    return initialDatabaseDataJsonAdapter.fromJson(jsonString)
}

@Suppress("SameParameterValue")
private fun readJsonFileFromAssets(
    context: Context,
    fileName: String,
): String? {
    val json = try {
        val inputStream: InputStream = context.assets.open(fileName)
        val size: Int = inputStream.available()
        val byteArray = ByteArray(size)
        inputStream.read(byteArray)
        inputStream.close()
        String(
            bytes = byteArray,
            charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8"),
        )
    } catch (ioException: IOException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
    return json
}
```

**MyRoomDatabase.kt**

@Database(
version = 14,
entities = [
Category::class,
EmojiLocalEntity::class,
Source::class,
Transaction::class,
],
exportSchema = true,
)
@TypeConverters(
AmountConverter::class,
CategoryIdsConverter::class,
CategoryConverter::class,
)
abstract class MyRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
// Dao declarations

```
companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: MyRoomDatabase? = null

    fun getDatabase(
        context: Context,
    ): MyRoomDatabase {
        val tempInstance = INSTANCE
        if (tempInstance != null) {
            // tempInstance.populateInitialData()
            return tempInstance
        }
        synchronized(
            lock = this,
        ) {
            val callback: Callback = object : Callback() {
                override fun onCreate(
                    supportSQLiteDatabase: SupportSQLiteDatabase,
                ) {
                    // do something after database has been created
                }

                override fun onOpen(
                    supportSQLiteDatabase: SupportSQLiteDatabase,
                ) {
                    // do something every time database is open
                    Executors
                        .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
                        .execute {
                            populateInitialData(
                                context = context,
                            )
                        }
                }
            }

            val instance = Room
                .databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    MyRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "finance_manager_database",
                )
                .addCallback(callback)
                .build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            return instance
        }
    }

    private fun populateInitialData(
        context: Context,
    ) {
        val myRoomDatabase = getDatabase(
            context = context,
        )
        myRoomDatabase.runInTransaction {
            CoroutineScope(
                context = Dispatchers.IO,
            ).launch {
                val initialDatabaseData = readInitialDataFromAssets(
                    context = context,
                )
                initialDatabaseData?.let {
                    // Do required operations
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you register your `CurrencyJsonAdapter` with your `Moshi.Builder`? Your [mcve] does not show your `Moshi.Builder` configuration.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I have done that.

Comment: @CommonsWare Added some more details. Not sure what all would be required. Please comment if anything else is necessary.

Comment: That all looks good. Are you sure that `moshi` is the object that you are using for creating the adapter that is trying to read in this JSON? IOW, are you perhaps accidentally creating more than one `Moshi` instance, and the one where you have registered `CurrencyJsonAdapter` is a different one than is the one that you are using for the JSON work?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have only one Moshi instance. And there is no retrofit or network data. All the data is from Room.

Comment: `ExceptionInInitializerError` suggests that you might accidentally be trying to use Moshi to deserialize data before you had the chance to `add(CurrencyJsonAdapter())` - is it possible? Hard to tell based on the code you attached, analyzing where `JsonUtilKt.readInitialDataFromAssets` gets called from and if there's a possibility it happens before `private val moshi` is getting initialized should help you resolve this.

Comment: @Egor Added complete `JsonUtil.kt`. `readInitialDataFromAssets()` is called from `MyRoomDatabase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue.

The root cause was the default `AmountJsonAdapter` created by Moshi was not internally using the `CurrencyJsonAdapter`.

#### Changes required,

1. Create custom JSON adapter for `Amount` rather than `Currency`.
2. Add `AmountJsonAdapter()` instead of `CurrencyJsonAdapter()` in `Moshi.Builder()`.
3. Disable moshi adapter generation for `Amount`.

#### After changes,

**Moshi Builder**

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(AmountJsonAdapter())
    .build()
```

**AmountJsonAdapter**

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class AmountJson(
    val currency: String,
    val value: Long = 0,
)

class AmountJsonAdapter {
    @ToJson
    fun toJson(
        amount: Amount,
    ): AmountJson {
        return AmountJson(
            currency = amount.currency.currencyCode,
            value = amount.value,
        )
    }

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(
        amountJson: AmountJson,
    ): Amount {
        return Amount(
            currency = Currency.getInstance(amountJson.currency),
            value = amountJson.value,
        )
    }
}
```

**Amount.kt**

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = false)
data class Amount(
  // Same code
)
```

Comment: Nice one man 